# Ansible parsing results from a loop

Tags: loops, parsing, ansible

Fairly new to ansible - here is what I am trying to do. I have created a playbook to monitor some servers. One of the tasks in the playbook deals with checking to see if the servers are backing up successfully.

Here is the task:

```
-name: Grabbing all of the files that were created today on Server1
 shell: find /back/up/location/ -maxdepth 1 -daystart -ctime 0 -print
 with_items:
   - '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
 when: item == "Server1"
 register: Server1
```

I am accessing the output here:

```
-debug: var=Server1.results
```

The output is displayed as:

```
ok: [Server1] => {
"changed": false, 
"Server1.results": [
    {
        "_ansible_item_result": true, 
        "_ansible_no_log": false, 
        "_ansible_parsed": true, 
        "changed": true, 
        "cmd": "find /back/up/location/ -maxdepth 1 -daystart -ctime 0 -print", 
        "delta": "0:00:00.007869", 
        "end": "2017-03-21 16:39:27.110185", 
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "_raw_params": "find /back/up/location/ -maxdepth 1 -daystart -ctime 0 -print",
                "_uses_shell": true, 
                "chdir": null, 
                "creates": null, 
                "executable": null, 
                "removes": null, 
                "warn": true
            }
        }, 
        "item": "Server1", 
        "rc": 0, 
        "start": "2017-03-21 16:39:27.102316", 
        "stderr": "", 
        "stderr_lines": [], 
        "stdout": "/back/up/location/\n/back/up/location/FULL-2017-03-22_14-22",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "/back/up/location/", 
            "/back/up/location/FULL-2017-03-22_14-22"
        ]
    }
]
```

However, I really only care about this:

```
          ` "stdout_lines": [
            "/back/up/location/", 
            "/back/up/location/FULL-2017-03-22_14-22"
        ]`
```

in order to do the following comparison:

```
-debug: msg="Backup was successful"
 when: Server1.results|length != 0
```

Is there a way within ansible to parse `Server1.results` to only contain the `stdout_lines` field? Open to any suggestions and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you iterate over hosts with loop and not with hosts pattern as it usually done in Ansible?

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov I guess I was unaware of this

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov does the .split attribute apply to lists in ansible?

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use:
-debug: var=Server1.results[0].stdout_lines

Comment: Wrong. `results` is a list.

Comment: You're right. It should be Server1.results[0].stdout_lines.